# Change upload folder on apache

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

By default there is /var/www folder and inside there are my php scripts. One of the functions of my project is uploading images. I don't want to upload images inside /var/www/mysite/upload, i want to upload them on another drive. For that purpose I have folder for storing uploaded images but when calling my script for uploading it happens nothing, I'm not familiar with ubuntu and apache so I don't know what to add inside apache configuration to enable uploading in specific folder or there is something else that i must do inside ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with symbolic links, for instance, you have /var/www/mysite, and you want to upload images to /mnt/another/location, just run

```
ln -s /var/www/mysite/upload /mnt/other/location
```

(do not forget read/write access rules)
@see http://linux.die.net/man/1/ln

Comment: So that means when php script upload and store image by default in /var/www/myproj/upload and after running that ln command in another execution of php script it will automatically transfer images on that other location?

Comment: Nope, it means that /var/www/myproj/upload is no longer a folder, but a link to another folder (roughly a shortcut). It is not a php feature but a unix system functionality.